# how to do on click tracking only on css not hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Partly done, but don't know how to do on click only on css not hidden elements

```js
$('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]').on('click', function(){
  var clicked = this;
  $('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]').each(function(i){
    if (this == clicked) dataLayer.push({ 'event':'Contact Us Click','Number':i});
  });
});
```

Comment: Do U want to hide or disable all ~similar elements, if one of them is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `:visible` jQuery selector.

```
$('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]:visible').on('click', function(){
  var clicked = this;
  $('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]').each(function(i){
    if (this == clicked) dataLayer.push({ 'event':'Contact Us Click','Number':i});
  });
});
```

Comment: $('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]:visible') is not helping. For some reason it still see the object  here is the link https://www.thedigitalinsights.com/

Comment: You want the click event only to be applied on elements that aren't hidden. The selector logic to target not hidden elements is the :visible selector. If you can further explain what are you after it'd help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use ID's (provided each class element has an ID):

```
$('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]').on('click', function(){
  var id = this.id;
  $('[class*="button"][href*="/contact/"]').each(function(){
    // find some way to get the value of i
    if (this.id == id) dataLayer.push({ 'event':'Contact Us Click','Number':i});
  });
});
```